# Is there a tile template catalog for windows 10 anywhere online?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I'm looking for the new tile templates for windows 10 and so I searched for the catalog, but all I found was the well known catalog for windows (phone) 8/8.1:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx

Do anyone know a link for the new tile template catalog for windows 10?

Greetings from a cloudy Germany
Ralf Ellersiek

Comment: Don't think there is one out for the public yet. There are rumors they might be adding Large Tile & Long Tile sizes though.

Comment: I watched a Windows 10 Event on MS virtual academy. They showed new tile templates and tile notification possibilities (I think, this was more than rumor). I will contact Jerry for more informations.

Comment: They said there isn't any new tile templates coming, instead they are introducing adaptive tiles. Source: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-762

Comment: @robertftw thanks. Thats the reason, why I didn't found a new tile catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@robertftw gave the correct answer: No more templates, adaptive tiles are the new way. And follow the [channel9-Link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-762): there you will get a lot of informations about adaptive tiles.
Thanks again to @robertftw.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 uses "adaptive tile templates", a flexible markup that allows you to achieve a wide variety of designs instead of a set of specific templates.

Learn all about adaptive here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/06/30/adaptive-tile-templates-schema-and-documentation.aspx